# I want to create a dynamic list using JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Hi everyone I wanna create a dynamic list for my header menu **(Please refer snap at below you will get idea)**. The list data is coming from API request on page load, the structure of the JSON data looks like below. Actually this is php array but at end see I have made is JSON data. anyhow I am getting this data and can able to loop in ajax success call too.

**[Please refer note and last html code to append thats the structure i want.  also see the snap i have uploaded I think snap says everything]**

```
  <?php 
$categories = array
(
    '0' => array
        (
            'id' => 1,
            'Name' => 'New Category',
            'sub' => array
                (
                )

        ),

    '1' => array
        (
            'id' => 3,
            'Name' => 'ddd',
            'sub' => array
                (
                    '0' => array
                        (
                            'id' => 4,
                            'Name' => 'test1',
                            'parent_id' => 3,
                            'sub' => array
                                (
                                )

                        ),

                    '1' => array
                        (
                            'id' => 5,
                            'Name' => 'Test123 recipe',
                            'parent_id' => 3,
                            'sub' => array
                                (
                                )

                        ),

                    '2' => array
                        (
                            'id' => 6,
                            'Name' => 'abceg',
                            'parent_id' => 3,
                            'sub' => array
                                (
                                    '0' =>array(
                                    'id' => 7,
                                    'Name' => 'xyz',
                                    'parent_id' => 6,
                                    'sub' => array
                                        (
                                        )
                                    )
                                )

                        )   

                )

        )

);
header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode($categories);
?>
```

So only thing I want is logic to arrange my menu, I am using this library which made it little easy for me to arrange. [mega menu](https://codyhouse.co/gem/mega-dropdown/)

Now suppose if category ddd in above json array is parent to test1, test123 receipe, abceg then these categories should fall under ddd then the structure should look like this

```
|ddd|
  |test1| 
  |test123 recipe|
  |abceg|
```

Now again from JSON data you can see xyz category falls under abceg so the final structure should look like this

```
|ddd|
  |test1| 
  |test123 recipe|
  |abceg|
      |xyz|
```

Please help me with this. Here is what I trid so far and I am getting upto 2 level hirerchy.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log('in');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../get_list_data/mydata-json.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        success: function (data) {
            var items = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].parent_id == 1 && data[i].id != 1) {

                    items.push('<li class="has-children"><a href="">' + data[i].name + '</a></li>');
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        if (data[i].parent_id == 1 && data[i].id == data[i + 1].parent_id) {
                            items.push('<ul class="cd-secondary-dropdown is-hidden"><li class="go-back"><a href="#1">Menu</a></li><li class="see-all"></li><li class="has-children "><a href="travail.html">' + data[i + 1].name + '</a><ul class="is-hidden"><li class="go-back"><a href="#1">' + data[i].name + '</a></li></ul></li></ul></li> ');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $('.parent-list').append(items.join(''));
        }, error: function (status) {
            console.log("failed");
        }
    });
})
```

**NOTE:** that first list items if has children then on hover we will get its children in another side pop-up if second list item also has children then we will get its children items below it. Please refer  [mega menu](https://codyhouse.co/gem/mega-dropdown/) for html structure. Else I have a simple structure for please use this

```
<h2 class="main-menu">Magasiner par catégorie</h2>
<a href="#1" class="cd-close">Close</a>
<ul class="cd-dropdown-content parent-list">
    <li class="has-children main-category">
        <a href="">Affaires, Industrie</a>
        <ul class="cd-secondary-dropdown is-hidden">
            <li class="go-back"><a href="#1">Menu</a></li>
            <li class="see-all"></li>
            <li class="has-children ">
                <a href="travail2.html">Sécurité au travail</a>
                <ul class="is-hidden">
                    <li class="go-back"><a href="#1">Magasiner par catégorie</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="divers.html">Accessoires divers</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul> <!-- .cd-secondary-dropdown -->
    </li> <!-- .has-children -->
</ul>
```

The main difficulty I am facing is while looping only I have to get to know wheather this item has level1 , level2 or final level. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to nest the elements at server end and then just loop through elements ?

Comment: Yeah I am getting data can loop upto 2 level. You just take my data and apply your logic to get desired output rest leave it on me.

Comment: Why don't you try the nested arrays in your `php` code instead of `parent_id` ?

Comment: Jyoti babu please provide your answers I cant change anything. Whatver I am following is has its own standards so please provide your answers if you can .

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja I have changed the JSON data can now try?